# Filter get_template_part() $args array

Tags: filters, get-template-part

I'd like to be able to pre-populate all occurances of the get_tempate_part $args when setting up a theme.

```
get_template_part( string $slug, string $name = null, array *$args* = array() )
```

Several action hooks exist within the `get_template_part` function and within `locate_template` which is also called by get_template_part, get_header, get_footer and the like but no filters are applied.
The best I've been able to fashions is to modify every instance of my themes call to get_template_part like so:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'views/loop', 'index', apply_filters( 'filter_template_part_args', [], 'loop' ) ); ?>
```

and run a custom filter like so:

```
add_filter( 'filter_template_part_args', function( $args, $slug, $name = '' ) {

    $defaults = [
        'id'        => esc_attr( basename( $slug ) ),
        'tag'       => 'div',
        'class'     => '',
        'container' => 'container',
        'row'       => 'row',
    ];

    return \wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    ;
```

} );

the above function work around - whilst being maintenance heavy – works for the individual teamplate_part calls made in the theme, but fails for existing calls from wordpress defaults (get_footer, get_header, etc)

Am I missing some key bit of info?
Yes, get_header() will except an $args param – but my theme is rapidly filling up with multiple code chunks that make extensibility painful and very un-DRY

Comment: $args was introduced to give us a way of passing variables to template parts without having to resort to global variables. It looks like you’re totally overworking things when what you want to do is use a global variable.

Comment: Please don't mistake my misuse of term global to indicate a global Variable. A better term might have been 'system wide'. I too find globals and statics to be a lazy way to pollute a system. I have removed my use of the term from my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such filter, so what you're doing is about the best you can do. However, you can optimise a bit by creating functions that wrap the template functions while applying your filter:

```
add_filter(
    'filter_template_part_args',
    function( $args, $slug, $name = null ) {
        $args = wp_parse_args(
            $args,
            [
                'id'        => esc_attr( basename( $slug ) ),
                'tag'       => 'div',
                'class'     => '',
                'container' => 'container',
                'row'       => 'row',
            ]
        );

        return $args;
    }
)

function mytheme_get_template_part( $slug, $name = null, $args = [] ) {
    $args = apply_filters( 'filter_template_part_args', $args, $slug, $name );

    get_template_part( $slug, $name, $args );
}

function mytheme_get_header( $name = null, $args = [] ) {
    $args = apply_filters( 'filter_template_part_args', $args, 'header', $name );

    get_header( $name, $args );
}
```

Then you can just do the same with `get_sidebar()` and `get_footer()`, and you should be covered for all the main template functions:

```
function mytheme_get_footer( $name = null, $args = [] ) {
    $args = apply_filters( 'filter_template_part_args', $args, 'footer', $name );

    get_footer( $name, $args );
}

function mytheme_get_sidebar( $name = null, $args = [] ) {
    $args = apply_filters( 'filter_template_part_args', $args, 'sidebar', $name );

    get_sidebar( $name, $args );
}
```

Comment: Will +1 this answer as it does provide a working solution. Doesn't help us with our main goal of harnessing core functionality and thereby minimising the need for custom functions but it will aid us in decoupling our template files from framework dependancies